# Android alertDialog gradient background

Tags: android, background, border, android-alertdialog, gradient

I am using AlertDialog with gradient background, but I have problem with borders, which are displaying very bad as you can see on the image. Is there any way how to get rid od them?

[image]

MyAlertDialog

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog { 
public MyAlertDialog(Context context,int theme)
{  
    super(context,theme);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

}

in an Activity:

```
MyAlertDialog myDialog = new MyAlertDialog(ActionShowActivity.this,R.style.Theme_CustomDialog);   
MyAlertDialog.setMessage("text");
MyAlertDialog.show();
```

Whole style file for Theme_CustomDialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
</style>
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog">

  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
  <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_blue</item>
  <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>



</style>
</resources>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why there is still a border?